# Python: Batching tweets in an array using tweepy stream listener

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a requirement to iterate over tweets using tweepy stream listener, batch them maybe every 5-10 tweets, store it in an array and perform some logic using the array of tweets.  Looking for help in how to batch them with the `on_data` object under streamlistener class.

```
class stdoutlistener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
         data = json.loads(data)
         print data

if i do something like this:
    i = 0
    records=[]
    while i<5:
         for item in data:
             records.append(item)
             i = i+1
    <do some logic>         
    records=[]
```

it iterates over each item in the tweet object (like contributors, text, id, source etc.), but does not iterate over tweets itself.

How can I batch tweets in 5s or 10s with the on_data class and store them in a Python array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best way to do it will be `api.search` method, by fetching 10 results, and using your stream's `track` parameter as search query `q` in search method. On linux you can use a `cron` to auto-run your script on a regular interval. Or you could start a `Thread` in your script to implement `do-something`-`sleep`-`do-something`-`sleep`..... cycle.

And it is iterating over each item because `on_data` method is called for each data received to stream, not on collection of data (which would've been a list).

Here is work-around

```
container = []
class stdoutlistener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        global container
        container.append(data)
        if len(container) > 10:
            for each in container:
                # Perform operation on each
            container = []
```

I've created a variable container, and keep appending `data` from stream to it, if there are more than 10 elements, you should perform your operation, and later empty the `container`.

Comment: Great, can you mark this answer as 'solved', and upvote it.